# How to restart a loop in Javascript whilst decrementing a global variable

Tags: javascript, for-loop, global-variables, decrement

I want the if statement (line 10) to detect when the next string in the array (line 1) is not matching the string in index0 (outputString0). And then to decrement the variable testLength (line 11) to slice the last character off the strings to allow them to be compared again in the next loop iteration to determine whether they are still matching. Then I want the loop to restart by setting i back to 0, which will increment to 1 once the loop is re-started (line 12).

But it seems to create an infinite loop. Is it because I am trying to modify the global variable testLength (line 11) from within the if statement?

```
const wordInput = ['fasts', 'fasta', 'fasts', 'fasts', 'fasts'];
let testLength = 5;

let outputString0 = wordInput[0].toString();
outputString0 = outputString0.slice(0, testLength);

for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  output = wordInput[i].toString();
  output = output.slice(0, testLength);

if ((this['outputString' + i] = output) !== outputString0) {      
  testLength = testLength - 1;   
  i = 0; continue;    
}

  else {
    this['testString' + i] = output;
    continue;
  }
};
```

I attempted to move the global variable testLength to inside the for loop, but the console also returns an error. Not sure what to do next.

Comment: Either you have a single `outputString0`, then just directly refer to that variable, or you have multiple different `outputStrings`, then make them an array and index into that. Same for the `testString`.

Comment: Thanks Bergi. I was avoiding indexing the outputStrings variables into an array as I want to directly compare them for equality, which I believe can't be done with items in an array.

Comment: Sure one can. Use an array.